# How to add ShareThis link field into View

Tags: views, social-network

I have a view and I want to add ShareThis(module enabled) link to each result of the view.
How this can be achieve so that any of the result row of the View will be shared on social networking sites.

Comment: Pankaj, I'm adding this comment here to "help" you to get you going with suggesting edits: make sure that the edits you suggest are actually (way) more then just correcting 1 or 2 words, or changing the format a little bit. Instead add module links, correct typos, fix grammar, etc. Otherwise "we" (the reviewers) are assumed to "reject" such "insufficient" edit enhancements. And there is a rule that if you have a balance of "5 more rejected edits as compared to accepted edits", you'll be blocked from suggesting edits for 7 days (!!!). Just trying to help you to get going, ok?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, Ok I got it.

Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: OK, thank you for confirming, I look forward to reviewing your next series of suggestions. If they'll turn out to actually take my above considerations into account, know that pretty sure "I" will approve all such suggestions that I see showing up in the review queue. And if you want, contact @AdrianCidAlmaguer (+ say hello from me!) about how I made a similar comment to him about some of his wiki edit suggestions (after I "had" to reject like a dozen of them, which I hated but "had" to do). From my reviews of his wiki suggestions it seems like he indeed accepted my suggestion ...

Answer (score 1):

Please check images for how to use sharethis filed within views

[image]

[image]

[image]

RESULT PAGE:

[image]